# MVC3 @Html.RadioButtonfor Pass data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, radiobuttonfor

Basically what I am trying is to create a **feedback form** with a question which has four answers (Radio Button) using MVC.

**In View**: I am able to get questions and answers in view with radiobutton to each answer.

**In Controller**: I am confused here.

I would like to send selected question & there answers from View to controller.

**My view** :

```
@model  IEnumerable SQLOperation.Models.QuestionClass.Tabelfields


@{int i = 0;}


     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
     using (Html.BeginForm("Question", "home", new {email=item.Email}))
     {   

         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName,item)

         <br /><br />   
         if (item.Option1 != "")
         {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option1, item)                
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option1)
                    <br /><br />                
         }

         if (item.Option2 != "")
         {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.SelectedOption, item.Option2)              
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option2)
                    <br /><br />
         }

         if (item.Option3 != "")
         {           
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option3)              
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option3)
                    <br /><br />
         }


         if (item.Option4 != "")
         {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option4)             
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option4) 
                    <br /><br />     
         }
         i = (Int16)i + 1;


         if (Model.Count() == i)
         {
                <input name="btnsumbit" type="submit" value="Submit Feedback" 
                style="font-family:Segoe UI Light;font-size:medium;"/>
         }
     }
 }
```

**My Controller** :

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Question(string email)
    {
        var tf = new QuestionClass.Tabelfields();

        IList<QuestionClass.Tabelfields> viewmodel = new List<QuestionClass.Tabelfields>();
        var q = QuestionClass.getallQuestion(email).ToList();

        foreach (SQLOperation.Models.Question item in q)
        {
            QuestionClass.Tabelfields viewItem = new QuestionClass.Tabelfields();

            viewItem.Email = item.Email;
            viewItem.QuestionID = item.QuestionID;
            viewItem.QuestionName = item.QuestionName;
            viewItem.Option1 = item.Option1;
            viewItem.Option2 = item.Option2;
            viewItem.Option3 = item.Option3;
            viewItem.Option4 = item.Option4;                
            viewmodel.Add(viewItem);
        }
         return View(viewmodel);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Question")]
    public void Question(string Email,QuestionClass.Tabelfields tf)
    {

    }
```

**My Model**:

```
public class QuestionClass

{

  public static FeedbackDatabaseDataContext context = new FeedbackDatabaseDataContext();
    public class Tabelfields : Question
    {
        //public decimal QuestionID { get; set; }
        //public string Email { get; set; }
        //public string QuestionName { get; set; }
        //public string Option1 { get; set; }
        //public string Option2 { get; set; }
        //public string Option3 { get; set; }
        //public string Option4 { get; set; }
        public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
    }


    public static List<Question> getallQuestion(string email)
    {
        var list = (from q in context.Questions where q.Email == @email select q);

        return list.ToList();
    }
```

}

I didn't get the question and it's selected option with appropriate Email in controller.

How can I get it in controller?

Comment: OK
public ActionResult Question(string email)
{
var tf = new QuestionClass.Tabelfields();

IList<QuestionClass.Tabelfields> viewmodel = new List<QuestionClass.Tabelfields>();
var q = QuestionClass.getallQuestion(email).ToList();
            
foreach (SQLOperation.Models.Question item in q)
{
QuestionClass.Tabelfields viewItem = new QuestionClass.Tabelfields();

viewItem.Email = item.Email;
viewItem.QuestionID = item.QuestionID;
viewItem.QuestionName = item.QuestionName;
viewItem.Option1 = item.Option1;
viewItem.Option2 = item.Option2;
viewmodel.Add(viewItem);
}
return View(viewmodel);
}

Answer (score 1):

To, start with include a breakpoint in your view and check if the values are being passed or not.

Next, change your method signature from

```
 public void Question(string Email,QuestionClass.Tabelfields tf)
```

to

```
 public void Question(string email, QuestionClass.Tabelfields tf)
```

Also, I see you have used some strange syntax ( considering m also new to MVC ) where you could have simply used this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName)
```

instead of this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName,item)
```

and also, I have seen you [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1261518/ajay), I know you are new to StackOverflow, so Welcome to StackOverflow ! you might want to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59758/182450) & [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16721/182450) as well. Cheers !

**Update :**

You are using this for displaying a radio button...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option1, item)
```

what is item.Option1, I can see you have commented out Opion1,2,3,4. Or are you still using them ?

A very simple way of implementing this would be something like this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, "Option1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, "Option2")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, "Option3")
```

or you can also use,

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option2)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option3)
```

provided values exist in item.Option1/2/3/4 and are all of them are different.

Comment: Thank you for rply.
I have made changes in view and also in controller like this

using (Html.BeginForm("Question", "home", new { email = item.Email, qid = item.QuestionID,qname=item.QuestionName ,option=item.SelectedOption}))

my Controller
public void Question(string Email, int qid,string qname,string option)

when i run this i get email,qid,qname but not get option selected of one question.

can u tell what changes i have to do in @html.beginform and in controller?

thank you

Comment: Thank you for reply,
how can I return the select radiobutton with appropriate answer to controller??
I have change this but I am not getting values in controller

Comment: problem solved

 @for (int row = 0; row < Model.Count; row++)

{
      @Html.EditorFor(x => x[row].FirstName )

}

Thank you for help